# jQuery add fields data into array to display under textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 text input fields like first-name,last-name and age and a ADD button. I also have a textarea where I want to display the added data as a value of textarea when click on ADD button.

I write some code but its only giving me the latest value of 3 input fields data inside textarea but I want to display all added data with comma separated inside textarea. example: Arora Shetty 25, Alok Kumar 30 etc. using jquery.

Here is the code i wrote

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"> 
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<textarea id="fetch_here"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_data">ADD</button>
```

jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_data').click(function() {
    var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();
    var user_data = $('#fetch_here').val(first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' ' + age);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<textarea id="fetch_here"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_data">ADD</button>
```

How can i add multiple data inside textarea?

Comment: `add_data != add_flower`

Comment: And it works fine in the snippet. What's the problem?

Comment: I need to add multiple data. right now its adding the most recent data if you update the last data is gone. I need to grab all data that added and no data will disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the previous text from the `textarea` before you assign the new value into it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_data').click(function(){
     var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
     var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
     var age = $('#age').val();
     var user_data = $('#fetch_here').text(
       $('#fetch_here').text() +
       first_name+' '+last_name+' '+age + '\n' );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"> 
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<textarea id="fetch_here"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_data">ADD</button>
```

Comment: @user3443037 I gave you the first answer. This is not fair at all.

Comment: @PraveenKumar don't act childish. Is that the rule that who gave first answer need to be accepted

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Agree with you on being childish, but isn't that fair. LoL. Bro, everyone spend their time here to get something out... Anyway... `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use an array to simplify your code, then, use:

- `.push()` to add a piece of data,
- `.join()` to join all the array elements with the string you want,

Then, you only need to get the current value of the `textarea` before replacing (adding) its content.

```js
$('#add_data').click(function() {
  var data = [];
  data.push($('#first_name').val());
  data.push($('#last_name').val());
  data.push($('#age').val());
  var current_val = $('#fetch_here').val();
  $('#fetch_here').val(current_val + data.join(' ') + '\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<textarea id="fetch_here"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_data">ADD</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alright for multiple data you need to append.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_data').click(function() {
    var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();
    var user_data = $('#fetch_here').val($('#fetch_here').val() + "\n" + first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' ' + age);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<textarea id="fetch_here"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_data">ADD</button>
```